# How to Implement firebase authentication fields with database fields with android studio app?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I know how to use the Firebase with phone authentication or with email but I have to use with both - The phone number and email number in my app to store on the database.
Is it possible ? 
If it is then please help with below.
I have a field of my authentcation with phone otp on firebase.
How to store the phone number from authentication table to the Database table with other fields.

Comment: Hey @BHASKAR do mark the answer as correct by clicking the V or tick type looking button next to the answer, as this helps people on stack overflow with similar questions, and I'd appreciate that too. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just put both the options for your users. You can put a button for signing in with Google ID and another one to put their phone numbers to sign in.

If you don't know how to do so, you just have to add relevant buttons and in `java` part, you can use something like this:

This is the part for getting and verifying OTP, signing in with Google ID and phone number.

There's more to it, like using the `signIn()` method in `onClickListener()` of your app's Google signIn button, but I think you can do this yourself.

```java
private void signIn(){
        Intent sIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(sIntent,RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);

        if(requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN){
            GoogleSignInResult result  = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if(result.isSuccess()){
                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Auth went wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account){
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(),null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    Log.d("Tag","SignInWithCredential: success");

                    FirebaseUser fUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                    assert fUser != null;

                    // do what you want on successful signIN, like storing the email using ref
                }
                else{
                    Log.w("TAG","SignInWithCredential: failure", task.getException());
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Authentication failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void GetOTP(){

        String pn = phone.getText().toString();

        if(pn.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Phone number is required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(pn.length()<10){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Valid Phone number is required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
            PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(pn,60, TimeUnit.SECONDS,this,mCallBacks);
    }

    PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallBacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
            super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);

            otp = s;
        }
    };

    private void verifyCode(){

        String code = cd.getText().toString();
        String pH = phone.getText().toString();
        if(code.equals("") && pH.equals(""))
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Nothing to validate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else {
            try {
                PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(otp, code);
                signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("exception",e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Invalid credentials",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }

    private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential){
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class));
                }
                else if(task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "OTP is incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

After you have got the emailID or the phone number, you can just make it the `identifier` of your user in the Firebase database.

What I mean from this, is that you can just save all other details of that user under the phone number/ email you got.

It looks something like this in code:

```java
//email is the email of the user and phone is the phone Number

if(email==null){
  DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
  ref.child("users").child(phone).child("username").setValue(uName);

  // you can set other details in the same way

}

else if(phone==null){
  DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
  ref.child("users").child(email).child("username").setValue(uName);

  // you can set other details in the same way

}

// uName is the username you want to store for the user
```